# How to connect Excel to MS SQL and get data WITH column names?

Tags: t-sql, excel, ado, vba

One of my users wants to get data into Excel from SQL 2008 query/stored proc.

I never actually did it before.

I tried a sample using ADO and got data but user reasonably asked - where are the column names?

How do I connect a spreadsheet to an SQL resultset and get it with **column names**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the field names are in the recordset object already.. just needed to pull them out.

```
i = 1
For Each objField In rs.Fields
    Sheet1.Cells(1, i) = objField.Name
    i = i + 1
Next objField
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of Excel you are using but in Excel 2007 you can just connect to the SQL DB by going to *Data* -> *From Other Sources* -> *From SQL Server*. After you select your server and database, your connection will be created. Then you can edit it (*Data* -> *Connections* -> *Properties*) where in the *Definition* tab you change the *Command type* to SQL and enter your query in the *Command text* box. You can also create a view on the server and just point to that from Excel.

This should do it unless I misunderstood your question.

Comment: I use 2003.. However - in your answer on 2007 - will you get column names with the resultset from SQL?? thats the question (not how to get data - thats simple, but how to get it with column names - see bold font in the question).. Cheers

Comment: you would get the column names, yes.

Comment: I bet this feature is in 2003 as well -- I just don't have it in front of me to tell you what the exact interface steps are. I am sure that if you click around you will find it, though. There is a benefit in using the built-in Excel features and not VBA.